# Android weight with margins and paddings

Tags: android, layout, margin, padding

I need to be able to use relative sizes for paddings - to be bigger or smaller depending on the device's resolution and dpi.

For example, if my view is wide 100px, I'd like to have 10px padding left and 10px padding right.
But, if it runs on a higher density screen, and it is say 250px, I need the left and right padding to be both 25pixels each.

Hardcoding pixels or dp doesn't seem reasonable, also I prefer to avoid code-behind scaling logic if I can get away with it. I also prefer NOT to use any additional weighted empty views to gain the same effect. Not sure how I can simulate padding with it either way.

Is there a way to do this from the xml? Or do I have to scale them based on the device resolution/dpi from the code behind?

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific. Margin, Padding and Weight all have very different goals. Weight will set your view's width and/or height, but not the margin. Padding is for *inside* the widget/view itself, so this is even further from the weight attribute.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn point taken, question revised.

Comment: you say DP(i) doesn't seem reasonable, why exactly not? They are not hardcoded pixels. They are Dots per Inch. They will do exactly what you want. 8dpi (Google's adviced margin) will be more pixels on a high resolution screen than on a low resolution screen.

Comment: Using dpi means it will look exactly the same size in inches on different devices. That's cool, but as I have aligned stuff using layout_weight, using dpi in some cases  (e.g. for padding) will result in some unpleasent layout discrepancy.

Comment: Then maybe your question should rather be about those exceptional cases where it doesn't work :)

Comment: @StefandeBruijn I think the question asked like this is simple enough. As I said, the layouts are already aligned using layout_weight, ergo - percentages. One cannot use percentages and **force** parts of an inch regardless of screen size (dp) within the same layout.

Comment: Best solution I found tell now is weighted empty views.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really "relative sizes for paddings" but I think using an Android [dimension value defined in XML](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) will do what you want.  It's hard to guess from your question as you want to avoid "hardcoding pixels" but also "do this from the xml" ;)

The link above gives this example;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="textview_height">25dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textview_width">150dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="ball_radius">30dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="font_size">16sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then;

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="@dimen/textview_height"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/textview_width"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"/>
```

The Android SDK itself uses this approach;

In e.g. `values/dimens.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

`values-sw600dp/dimens.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!--
     Customize dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml (such as
     screen margins) for sw600dp devices (e.g. 7" tablets) here.
    -->

</resources>
```

You can target `values-FOO` at API levels, screen sizes, portrait vs landscape, combinations of the above "and more" when you are [providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) by using "Configuration qualifier names".